# error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’

Tags: c++, gcc, cilk

I'm using:
gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 4.9.2-0ubuntu1~14.04) 4.9.2

I'm trying to compiler the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cilk/cilk.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    cout << "\nStart\n";
    cilk_for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        cout << "I = " << i;
    }

}
```

But get the following error:

```
g++ -fcilkplus Cilk_1.cpp 
Cilk_1.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
Cilk_1.cpp:9:12: error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’
  cilk_for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            ^
Cilk_1.cpp:9:23: error: ‘i’ was not declared in this scope
  cilk_for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                       ^
```

What is wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: do you need #include <stdio.h>

Comment: @jdl: What exactly would that accomplish?

Comment: I'm learning cilk...

Comment: Something's wrong with the `cilk_for` macro. No idea what it is so no idea what. Run with `-E` to see preprocessed code and you'll soon figure out what's going on.

Comment: This is supposed to work according to the intel doc, is this a gcc bug?

Comment: Is the header properly included? I could imagine that if the header fails to be included somehow, that it parses `cilk_for` like a function call, which would give you the error.

Comment: @Nax: No, looks like the macro is not being expanded for some reason.

Comment: pull "int i" out of the loop and try... at least isolate more the problem

Comment: @jdl: What exactly would that accomplish?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, Seems to be a macro for an Intel extension that allows the loop to run in parallel. GCC's supported it since 4.9.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Ok, guess my guess was incorrect then. Thanks for enlightening me :) And yeah, I meant 98.

Comment: No problem. OP, as I said earlier, use `-E` to debug this.

Comment: Can GCC even support cilk out of the box? I think you are missing the compiler support for the `_Cilk_for` keyword.

Comment: @user3668129 `cilk_for` expands to `_Cilk_for `, what happens if you do the substitution yourself ?

Comment: maybe add the cilk lib with "-lcilkrts"? Also make sure your GCC is compiled with the cilk extension in the first place

Comment: @MicroVirus, [GCC mainline started to support Cilk Plus since 4.9](https://www.cilkplus.org/download#gcc-development-branch)

Comment: @chris: That link also specifically mentions "all features **except _Cilk_for**".

Comment: @MicroVirus, Apparently I can't read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [link Chris gave](https://www.cilkplus.org/download#gcc-development-branch) in the comments, it seems GCC 4.9 supports all features of the cilk extensions **except _Cilk_for** out of the box. Therefore, your compiler (GCC 4.9) does not have `cilk_for` support.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above, support for cilk_for was added in gcc 5.0.